Beta Distribution for a skewed distribution
Im trying to develop a distribution for a biological data set. It is a rate data set (0-1) of 8.9 million locations. 90% of the locations have a rate of 0, the mean is 0.002447 and the max is 1. When I tried to do parameter estimation using method of moments alpha=0.00427 and beta = 1.74. Due to the biological nature of the dataset its not appropriate to filter out the 0's or the upper limit but the extreme values of the parameters seem concerning. Is there any way to establish a proper beta distribution for this kind of data or would another distribution be better?
Any advice is greatly appreciated,

With this super high number of observations, you would be well served by having a very flexible model, in my opinion. I would suggest to model the data as having some probability (here 90%) of being 0, and some density when it is non-0. That density you can first target with a kernel-density estimator. If it has a very simple shape, you can see if a simpler model would provide a good fit, but be very aware that any statistical test will reject a fixed model with this amount of data. It is also worth centering, prioritising whatever scientific question led to collecting this data. Bon courage

What will you do with the distribution once you find or develop it?  Why do you need it? You can use splines to estimate a huge variety of distributions, but they aren't easily characterized with just one or two parameters.

@PeterFlom Essentially trying to differentiate between two different biological phenomenon within the data set, it is likely and expected that biological phenomenon A caused the majority of data points (0-0.005), and biological phenomenon B would be closer to (0.02-1) but we were advised to establish a beta distribution and then call a 99% CI to establish a cutoff of what is likely to be A in other data libraries taken at the same time.

What does a "rate of 0" really mean here?  If these are true zeros, forget about Beta distributions.  But otherwise, if they are zeros measured to finite precision, then the parameter estimates are likely to depend strongly on that precision, so you should include it in your procedure, such as treating your data as interval-valued rather than point-valued.

There is nothing obviously particularly wrong with your results (though your estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will be uncertain).   A Beta distribution with $\alpha = 0.00427$ and $\beta = 1.74$ has $90%$ of the probability below $10^{-11}$.
